# Unserialize с преобразованием символов utf8

Tags: php

Объект приходит с сервера сериализованным с символами в таком виде:

`&#1045;&#1074;&#1088;`

Сейчас для того, чтобы преобразовать его обратно и раскодировать эти символы, используется следующий набор команд:

```
$data = unserialize(stripslashes($data));
$data = json_decode(html_entity_decode(json_encode($data)), true);
```

Жесть какая. Можно это сделать как-нибудь короче?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Для приведённого примера достаточно сделать один-единственный html_entity_decode и больше ничего, зачем вы всю остальную жесть вообще нагородили?

Comment: @andreymal, потому что данные сериализованы (`a:40:{s:5:"...`) - если выполнить `html_entity_decode` до `unserialize`, то потом декодировать не получится, так как изменится количество символов в строке.

Comment: Такие важные подробности обязаны быть в тексте вопроса с полноценными примерами

Comment: @andreymal

> Объект приходит с сервера сериализованным

Знаете, как выглядят сериализованные объекты?

Comment: Если вы заинтересованы в получении ответа на свой вопрос, то это ваша задача — показать, как у вас всё выглядит, чтобы облегчить нам анализ и поиск решения вашей проблемы. Показанный вами пример **не** является сериализованным и для него достаточно выполнить один только html_entity_decode. Впрочем, даже если вы и покажете сериализованный пример — это не объясняет, зачем вы тут нагородили stripslashes и json

Comment: @andreymal, если бы я еще знал, как закодировать текст таким образом - конечно, сделал бы пример. А исходный объект настолько большой, что сюда его не поместишь.

Comment: Ну тогда и мы вряд ли сможем помочь. Даже если поиграться с сериализованными объектами, то какое-нибудь `html_entity_decode(unserialize(serialize('&#1045;&#1074;&#1088;')));` тоже отлично работает, а что там за жесть происходит с вашими объектами, мы не знаем

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = '&#1045;&#1074;&#1088;';
$data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$data = json_decode($data, true, 512, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars_decode(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given`